# How to get Vista Installer from a Toshiba laptop

Tags: virtualbox, windows-vista, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba laptop that came with Vista.  It runs much better with Ubuntu and I never want to go back.  I was so dead set that I removed the Vista partition.  Now I need some applications that will not work on WinE:

1. [Target Coupons](http://sites.target.com/site/en/supertarget/page.jsp?title=coupons_specials)
2. Skype with my webcam

I can always boycott target (and their site makes it very tempting), but the Jetson's feel of Skype is too tempting.  My webcam works in Linux, just not Skype.

Anyway, I want to install Vista on VirtualBox instead having to dual boot for these tasks.  I don't have a Vista disk, but I still have my product key.  The disk given by Toshiba doesn't seem to let me do a full re-install.  So, I have two issues:

1. How can I get my hands on a Vista install disk?
2. Will the Vista installer somehow recognize that it's VirtualBox (not a Toshiba) and block the install?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " The disk given by Toshiba doesn't seem to let me do a full re-install." Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

To "get you hands on" a Vista disk, you can borrow one from a friend [or download from a torrent site]- as long as the product key is unique and owned by you there shouldn't be a problem. I can't help you with the VM issue.

One example of back up for my claim, although SuperUser is not a legal resource:
[How can I get an existing Vista installation to a "clean" state (without an installation disc)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78883/how-can-i-get-an-existing-vista-installation-to-a-clean-state-without-an-insta)